# Can I have Azure Function with HTTP trigger without Storage Account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am confused is it possible to have Azure Function with HTTP trigger without Storage Account. I saw in msdn this info: "An HTTP trigger doesn't use the Storage account connection. All other trigger types require a valid Storage account connection string."
But If I try to publish by VisualStudio a project with such Azure Function,Http trigger it still asked me to create a Storage Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But If I try to publish by VisualStudio a project with such Azure Function,Http trigger it still asked me to create a Storage Account.

When you publishing the Http trigger to azure, it asks you to create the storage account to the Function App, the storage account is required by the Functions runtime. See [Storage account requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#storage-account-requirements).

In the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage):

> **AzureWebJobsStorage**
>
> The Azure Functions runtime uses this storage account connection string for all functions except for HTTP triggered functions.

The storage is for Function App runtime not the http trigger, the storage account is also for other thing, like [storing logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsdashboard).